# Total time to HH:MM:SS to rdlc

Tags: c#, rdlc

this is the code i have right now. This code computes the total time in my rdlc using expressions.

```
(Sum(System.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!Number_of_Hours.Value).Hours)) &":"&(Sum(System.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!Number_of_Hours.Value).Minutes))
```

this code shows the total hours and minutes.

111:217

What I want to see is this.. is this possible ?

113:37

Comment: Is that even C#? It looks like VB.

Comment: C# doesn't use `&` to concatenate strings.

Comment: @mikez what will i use ?

Comment: @mikez and how can i show the format above

Comment: How can you change 111:217 to 113:37? What is the relation between the two?

Comment: @amarduplantier yes because it just total the Hours and minutes what i want to see is the format of time it should be  hh:mm

Comment: you can write a function to do the calculations(like converting minutes to hours) and then call that function in your expressions; check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195521/vs2010-report-designer-formatting-an-int-as-xd-yh-zm-in-rdlc

Answer (score 0):

Its a little unclear, but I think you are saying that you have an input of time as a string in the format like 111:217 where the minutes component can be >= 60. You want to display that in hh:mm where the minutes component is < 60.

TimeSpan.Parse() dosent seem to like the format your input is in. It expects the minutes < 60 and hours < 24. You will have to use the TimeSpan constructor. Give this code a try:

```
string input = "111:217";

// Split the string into pieces on ":"
string[] parts = input.Split(':');

// Create a TimeSpan from our pieces
int hours = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
int minutes = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);

TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);

// Show the time formatted
string formatted = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

Console.WriteLine(formatted);   

// Show the total time in minutes
double totalMinutes = time.TotalMinutes;

Console.WriteLine(totalMinutes);
```

Here is fiddle showing the code working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iEeA6J